# Finite State Automata (FSA): Repeated output problem

Tags: python, nlp, finite-automata

I'm constructing a FSA that print sheep ("baa...!") or cow ("moo...!") in which only even number of vowels are accepted. My FSA is as the following but I don't know why the accepted answers are repeated when there are more than 2 vowels in the given them.

Could you help me understand why it happens and how to fix this?

```
import openfst_python

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
import pywrapfst as fst
from fststr import fststr

# for visualizing the FSA
import graphviz
from IPython.display import display

def create_fsa(alphabet, fsa_str):
    """Create and compile an FSA given an alphabet and string representation
    
    Params
    ------
    alphabet: `List[str]` 
        Input alphabet of the FSA
    fsa_str: str 
        String representation of the FSA 
        
    Returns the FSA object
    """
    st = fststr.symbols_table_from_alphabet(alphabet)
    compiler = fst.Compiler(isymbols=st, osymbols=st, keep_isymbols=True, keep_osymbols=True)
    compiler.write(fsa_str)
    fsa = compiler.compile()
    
    return fsa
```

```
sheepcow_alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'm', 'o', '!']
sheepcow_fsa_str = """
0 1 b b 
1 2 a a
2 1 a a
2 3 a a
3 2 a a
1 4 ! !
4
0 5 m m
5 6 o o
6 5 o o
6 7 o o
7 6 o o
5 4 ! !
4
""" 


sheepcow_fsa = create_fsa(alphabet=sheepcow_alphabet, fsa_str=sheepcow_fsa_str)

# and visualizing FSA
sheepcow_fsa.draw("FSAs/sheepcow_fsa.dot", portrait=True)
src = graphviz.Source.from_file("FSAs/sheepcow_fsa.dot")
display(src)

# list of words for your own inspection
accepted_strings = ['baa!', 'moo!', 'baaaa!', 'moooooo!']
rejected_strings = ['b', '!', 'oo!', 'baaa!', 'maa!', 'baaa!']


# for the accepted list, the expected results should contain the input strings themselves
for s in accepted_strings:
    print('SheepCow FSA processes string %s: %s' % (s, fststr.apply(s, sheepcow_fsa)))


# rejected list
for s in rejected_strings:
    print('SheepCow FSA processes string %s: %s' % (s, fststr.apply(s, sheepcow_fsa)))
```

Output:

```
SheepCow FSA processes string baa!: ['baa!']
SheepCow FSA processes string moo!: ['moo!']
SheepCow FSA processes string baaaa!: ['baaaa!', 'baaaa!']. # repeated
SheepCow FSA processes string moooooo!: ['moooooo!', 'moooooo!', 'moooooo!', 'moooooo!']. # Repeated
SheepCow FSA processes string b: []
SheepCow FSA processes string !: []
SheepCow FSA processes string oo!: []
SheepCow FSA processes string baaa!: []
SheepCow FSA processes string maa!: []
SheepCow FSA processes string baaa!: []
```

I tried to sort out the input that only has even number of vowels but output is weird.

Comment: That FST library implements a non-deterministic state machine, right? (Or instead of forcing us to guess, add a link to the library.)

Comment: I think this is the link to the library: https://github.com/dmort27/fststr

Answer (score 0):

I think the library is working as it should. If you look at the generated FST (which you seem to have drawn using Graphviz), you'll see that there are multiple possible accepting paths for strings with more than one pair of vowels (since from state 2 the automaton can either go to state 1 or to state 3, and in both cases return to state 2).

The documentation for the library indicates that `apply` produces a list of "the unique paths through the resulting lattice". With your FST, distinct paths can have the same traduction, so when the library converts the paths to strings, it produces multiple copies of the same string.